# Git deleted and renamed dirs

Tags: git, github

I had a folders structure:

- tmpl
- tmpl3

I have deleted `tmpl` directory and than renamed `tmpl3` to `tmpl` next commit. Now I have actual folders on my local but on git - directory has been deleted. Git shows nothing to commit.

How to fix this?

Comment: git add tmpl, then git commit -m "meaningful message", git push origin master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't understands *renaming*. When you rename something, you need to remove it from git and then add it again.

Remove and add directory :

```
git rm --cached tmpl #Doesn't matter if it still exists or not
git add tmpl3
git commit
```

Some commands like `git mv` can help you do that :

```
git mv -r tmpl tmpl3
```